# How to bypass login screen in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a FB.getLoginStatus function that is there to bypass the login function if the user has already authorized the app:

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {

        userID = response.authResponse.userID;  
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change' , '#homepage');


        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);


      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change' , '#login');
      } else {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change' , '#login');
      }
     });
```

It works in that it checks the login status, but it quickly flashes the login screen before it jumps to the home screen. Is there a way I can completely avoid flashing the login screen and just load the home screen if the user is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a working solution:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){ 
    var to = data.toPage,
        from = data.options.fromPage;
     
    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
        if (from) from = '#' + from.attr('id');
         
        if (from === '#index' && to === '#second') {
            alert('Can not transition from #index to #second!');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
             
            // remove active status on a button, if transition was triggered with a button
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-shadow').css({'box-shadow':'0 0 0 #3388CC'});
        } 
    }
});
```

What you need to do here is add another layer of checking to this line:

```
if (from === '#index' && to === '#second') {
```

All you need to do is check if user has authorized through Facebook and redirect him programmatically using function **changePage()**.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-prevent-jquery-mobile-page-navigation/)**.

## Update

I forgot, this example may not work in your case because if you're checking it in the beginning you will not have destination page because you are here to determinate which page is first: login page or main page.

This code will help you in this case:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){ 
    var to = data.toPage;
     
    if (typeof to  === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
         
        if (to === '#second') {
            alert('Can not transition the page #second!');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
             
            // remove active status on a button, if transition was triggered with a button
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-shadow').css({'box-shadow':'0 0 0 #3388CC'});
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: I just needed to add {transition:'none'} to the $.mobile.pageContainer action. Thanks for your explanation but I believe it was more geared towards preventing navigation to a certain page, and was unfortunately not a fix for my situation.